# Is there a way to generate a confidence interval from a caret lm object?

Tags: r, r-caret

I would like to be able to generate a confidence interval from a model that I create with the package caret. This can be done using `predict(model, data, interval = "confidence")` when the model is created with `lm()`. However, when I try the same command with a model created with caret's `train()` function, I get the following error:

```
Error in extractPrediction(list(object), unkX = newdata, unkOnly = TRUE,  : 
  unused argument (interval = "confidence")
```

This is true even when I set `method = "lm"` in the `train` function. Does anyone know how to get a confidence interval from such an object? Preferably using `predict` so the format is the same.

Thanks!

Comment: Please read error messages and help pages. It's telling you there is no parameter to the `extractPrediction`-function named "interval". Since the inference model for resampling procedures is different than for the usual use of `lm`, you might want to adjust your expectations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found out how to do this! `caret` objects do in fact store the original model, beneath a huge pile of metadata. You can access this model with `my_model_name$finalModel`. Thus, to find the confidence interval, you would call `predict(my_model_name$finalModel, my_data, interval = "confidence")`.